# Single quotes and double quotes in perl

Tags: perl, postgresql, quotes, double-quotes

I'm a newbie in perl and I'm trying to execute an operating system command from a Perl script.

The operating system command is executed with [`IPC::Open3`](https://metacpan.org/module/IPC%3a%3aOpen3), and the command is like

```
$cmd = "mycommand --add \"condition LIKE '%TEXT%' \"";
```

This command is supposed to insert the string contained after the "add" into a database.

The problem is that it inserts the record in the database without the single quotes around `%TEXT%`, like this:

```
condition LIKE %TEXT%
```

If I execute the command at a command prompt it inserts the string correctly.

How should I format the double and single quotes so that it is inserted in the database correctly?

Thanks for the help

Comment: BTW if i execute the command in a prompt, it inserts the string correctly

Comment: As you can tell by printing `$cmd`, `$cmd = "mycommand --add \"condition LIKE '%TEXT%' \"";` stores the string `mycommand --add "condition LIKE '%TEXT%' "` in `$cmd`, which will pass the args `--add` and `condition LIKE '%TEXT%' ` to the command on a unix system. Is that what you're suppose to be passing?

Comment: What does the command line that you type in look like?

Comment: The command line that works OK is like this :  #mycommand --add "condition LIKE '%TEXT%'"

Comment: I'm guessing a `\\'` in your source string would be seen by perl as `\'` and passed to your shell which would interpolate it as `'` to be passed as a parameter to your program.

Answer (score 5):

By putting the command in a single string, you are inflicting upon it a pass through your system's shell.  (You don't mention if it's cmd.exe or bash or other fun stuff.)

Suggestions:

1. Creating your system command as an array of strings will avoid the shell re-interpolating your command line.
   `@cmd = ('mycommand', '--add', q(condition LIKE '%TEXT%'));`
2. Throw in extra backslashes to protect the single quotes from your shell.  Prepending `echo` to your command could help with the debugging....
3. (my personal favorite) Don't shell out for your Database access.  [`use DBI`](http://metacpan.org/module/DBI#NAME).

Comment: `IPC::Open3` is not like `system()` or `qx()`, there is no shell parsing. 1 and 3 are perfectly good answers though.

Comment: @jordanm: Check out line 273 of `IPC::Open3` (v1.12).  exec() is called on the 4th & later parameters.  (1..3 are shifted out at line 201.)  exec()'s documentation does indicate that a single string w/ shell characters produces a trip through the shell.

Answer (score 0):

```
$cmd = q{mycommand --add "condition LIKE '%TEXT%'"};
```

`qq` is for double-quoting , `q` is for single quoting.

This way it takes whole command as it is.

Comment: The way I like to think about it: `"..."` is the short form of `qq"..."` and `'...'` is the short form of `q'...'`.